# Markov property and homogeneity for "arbitrary" measurable set left and right of condition

Tags: proof-explanation, markov-chains, stopping-times

I have trouble with showing the Markov and homogeneity property of a homogenous Markov chain if we allow somewhat arbitrary sets left and right of the condition bar. To put it formally:

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a homogenous, time discrete Markov chain. Let $\tau_y := \min\{n \geq 1: X_n = y\}$ be the (random) return time to $y$ for $y \in E$ with state space $E$. Define $\mathbb{P}^x(\tau_y \leq k) := \mathbb{P}(\tau_y \leq k|X_0 = x)$ for $x \in E$ to be the probabilty that the chain visits $y$ if started in $x$ (or in the case of $x = y$ visits itself again after starting).

My scripture now states, that for some fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$

$$\exists \alpha \in [0,1]: \forall x \in E: \mathbb{P}^x(\tau_y \leq k) \geq \alpha \implies \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in E: \mathbb{P}^x(\tau_y > nk) \leq (1-\alpha)^n$$

We then use induction over $n$ to show the proposition. Trivial base case and induction hypothesis (IH) aside, the induction step goes like this:

$$\begin{array}{ll}
\mathbb{P}^x(\tau_y > (n+1)k) 
&= \mathbb{P}^x(\tau_y > (n+1)k|\tau_y > nk) \cdot \mathbb{P}^x(\tau_y > nk)
\\
&= \mathbb{P}^x(\tau_y > k) \cdot \mathbb{P}^x(\tau_y > nk)
\\
&\stackrel{(IH)}{\leq} (1-\alpha) \cdot (1-\alpha)^n = (1-\alpha)^{n+1}
\end{array}$$

The step that I refuse to believe without evidence is $\mathbb{P}^x(\tau_y > (n+1)k|\tau_y > nk) = \mathbb{P}^x(\tau_y > k)$. In my scripture, this is put off as a use of the Markov property and homogeneity, but I can't really show why that must be true.

I have already shown both the Markov and homogeneity property for expressions of the form $\mathbb{P}(X_n = i_n,\ldots,X_{l+1} = i_{l+1}|X_l = i_l,\ldots,X_0=i_0)$ and from there it is easy to generalize to events on the left side that can be expressed as a countable union of finitely many $``X_i=\ldots"$-terms on the left side, but the above probability $\mathbb{P}^x(\tau_y > (n+1)k|\tau_y > nk)$ having a possibly infinite amount of terms on *both* the left and right side and there being a non-$X_i$ expression on the right leaves me questioning.

I revoke my statement on having found a proof in I [this](https://www.amazon.de/Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie-Masterclass-Achim-Klenke/dp/366262088X) book by A. Klenke, I mixed it up with a different problem. Maybe someone different can point me to a proposition relevant to the question.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n\ge 0$. On the event $\{\tau_y>nk\}$ you have $\tau_y=nk+\tilde\tau_y$, where $\tilde\tau_y$ is the first time that $(X_{m+nk})_{m\ge 1}$ returns to $y$; that is, $\tilde\tau_y:=\inf\{m\ge 1: X_{m+nk}=y\}$. By the Markov property applied at time $nk$, the events $\{\tau_y>nk\}$ and $\{\tilde\tau_y>k\}$ are conditionally independent, given the value of $X_{nk}$, and  the latter has conditional probability equal to
$$
\Bbb P(\tilde\tau_y>k\mid X_{nk}=z)=\Bbb P^z(\tau_y>k)< 1-\alpha.
$$
**Amplification:** $\mathcal F_j$ is the history of $X$ up to time $j$. Because $\tau_y$ is a stopping time, the event $\{\tau_y>nk\}$ is $\mathcal F_{nk}$-measurable.
$$
\eqalign{
\Bbb P(\tau_y>(n+1)k)
&=\Bbb P(\tau_y>nk, \tilde\tau_y>k)\cr
&=\Bbb E\left[ 1_{\{\tau_y>nk\}} \Bbb P(\tilde\tau_y>k\mid \mathcal F_{nk})\right]\cr
&=\Bbb E\left[ 1_{\{\tau_y>nk\}} \Bbb P^{X_{nk}}( \tau_y>k)\right]\cr
&\le\Bbb E\left[ 1_{\{\tau_y>nk\}} (1-\alpha)\right]\cr
&=(1-\alpha)\Bbb P( \tau_y>nk).\cr
}
$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "By the Markov property applied at time $nk$"? I'm not sure, but isn't this part of what I wanted to prove in my question (that you can apply the property if the individual states for the chain on the left side is possibly infinite)?

Comment: I've added more detail to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. How do you go from $\mathbb{P}(\tilde{\tau}_y > k | \mathcal{F}_{nk})$ to $\mathbb{P}^{X_{nk}}(\tau_y > k)$? In your statement above the calculation you adress a similar fact for $X_{nk}$ instead of $\mathcal{F}_{nk}$. I apologize if I am too naive to understand this answer.

Comment: That's the Markov property: the conditional distribution of $\tilde\tau_y$, given $\mathcal F_{nk}$, is equal to the conditional distribution given $X_{nk}$; and conditional on  $X_{nk}=z$, the distribution of $\tilde\tau_y$ coincides with the $\Bbb P^z$-distribution of  $\tau_y$.

Comment: Ah yes, since I needed the equivalent definition of the Markov property for another problem, this is pretty clear now. Thank you. There is still one little thing I would like to know before I accept your answer: I get how one would conclude $\mathbb{P}(\tilde{\tau}_y > k|X_{nk} = z) = \mathbb{P}^z(\tau_y > k)$ intuitively by homogeneity, but (and I know I am reiterating my point) since there could be an uncountable number of sequences on the left side (because the space of natural number sequences is uncountable), how would one go about showing that the property still holds?

Comment: Oh wait, taking the probability of the complementary event and then using the property I have already shown (because $\mathbb{N}^{n(k+1)}$ is countable) and simplifying again makes this step trivial, doesn't it?